# Structlayout behaving incorrectly in debug build

Tags: c#, struct

Consider the following programm:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new magic
        {
            S = "Hello",
            C =
            {
                [0] = 'W',
                [1] = 'o',
                [2] = 'r',
                [3] = 'l',
                [4] = 'd',
            }
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        Console.ReadKey();    
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct magic
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public string S;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public char[] C;
    }
}
```

Why does this print `HeWor` when building with debug
and `World` (as expected) on release?
Tested on VS 2019 with .net 4.8

I know doing this is more than borderline, but is there any explanation behind this?

Comment: I got `HeWor` on debug and on release.

Comment: @SᴇM .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: @DavidG Framework, but 4.7.1, I will check with 4.8 in a second.

Comment: Executed as 32-bit or 64-bit? I get behavior that differs between x86 and x64 (x86 debug FW 4.6.1: `World`, x64 debug FW 4.6.1: `HeWor`)

Comment: You have `Prefer 32-bit` checked when on Release and unchecked on Debug. If you check it on Debug mode too, it will print `World`.

Comment: This is an alignment issue -- on 64-bit, strings take 2 more bytes than on x86 because the internal field layout is different. I forget the precise details; that would require diving into the CLR internals. This is not a safe/guaranteed way of aliasing, in any case; getting a pointer to the first element/character is safe this way, but not overlapping the references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no valid "expected" outcome for this; the behavior is completely undefined; what is happening is that you're *assigning* a string reference to `S` (which is also `C` obviously), then **lying** and talking to the array indexer code, but executing against an *instance* of a string. Since this is the interned `"Hello"`, you're overwriting the global interned `"Hello"`, but: the array indexer opcode only knows how to talk to arrays, and thus *gets the offset wrong*. The internal layout of a string and an array can be different (and clearly are, depending on the runtime, framework version, etc), so it can (and clearly does) update the bytes starting at the wrong offset from the object header.

As for why it *works* on some setups: again, undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is allowed to "work", where the air-quotes are important.

If you want to *correctly* get the offsets, then either use `fixed` or `ToSpan()`/`ToMemory()`. The first allows a `string` to be treated as a `char*`; the second allows a `string` to be treated as a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` (but you can use `MemoryMarshal` to upgrade a `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` to `Memory<char>`).

Examples:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Hello"); // Hello

// note: using MemoryMarshal.* is like using Unsafe.*; you
// are explicitly accepting the consequences if used incorrectly
var span = MemoryMarshal.AsMemory("Hello".AsMemory()).Span;
span[0] = 'W';
span[1] = 'o';
span[2] = 'r';
span[3] = 'l';
span[4] = 'd';
Console.WriteLine("Hello"); // World

// ditto, "unsafe" means you're accepting the consequences
fixed(char* c = "Hello")
{
    c[0] = 'd';
    c[1] = 'l';
    c[2] = 'r';
    c[3] = 'o';
    c[4] = 'W';
}
Console.WriteLine("Hello"); // dlroW
```

Also, it presumably doesn't *really* need to be said but... **don't do this!**